# How should I hang onto the ag-grid api with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, closures, ag-grid, react-hooks, ag-grid-react

[ag-grid](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid) recommends getting a pointer to the grid api as a variable in their onGridReady callback, if you need it. With React classes you would do this:

```
class MyGrid extends React.Component {
  ...
  onGridReady = params => {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
  }
  render() {
    // on subsequent calls still have this.gridApi...
    return <AgGridReact onGridReady={this.onGridReady} ... />;
  }
}
```

What is the proper pattern to do this with react hooks?  Here is my code so far;

```
const MyGrid = props => {
  let gridApi = null;
  const onGridReady = params => {
    gridApi = params.api;
  }
  return <AgGridReact onGridReady={onGridReady} ... />;
}
```

The problem is the "MyGrid" component function will be called multiple times, and once after the onGridReady function runs, resetting the variable to null before I use it.

Should I just make the variable global in the scope above?

```
let gridApi = null;
const MyGrid = props => { ... }
```

Or is this a good use case for something like "[useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)"?

Comment: I'd say to use `useState` hooks ? `const [gridApi, setGridApi] = useState(null)`

Comment: @Jonathan Hamel - That would work I never thought of that. Once set, this var will never change, is there any reason to use state over a module variable?

Comment: I think I could also useRef but don't know why I would do that over moving the var scope up - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why exactly do you need a reference to the grid api? Did you look into this guide for react 16+ https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/react-hooks/ ? Using react `refs` with `useRef` would also be a good option.

Comment: I need a ref to the gridApi to do things on window resize.  I saw useRef after the fact, that does like possibly the way to go. I wonder what is the benefit of useRef over a higher level closure variable?

Comment: Link no longer resolves

Answer (score 4):

Use this hook:

```
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react';

export default function useAgGrid() {
  const [gridApi, setGridApi] = useState();
  const onGridReady = useCallback(
    (params) => {
      const { api, columnApi } = params;
      setGridApi({ api, columnApi });
    },
    []
  );
  return {
    onGridReady,
    ...gridApi && gridApi
  };
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I want - how do you use it in the component?